# Get the total of a number in a loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, random

My program generates 2 random numbers from 1 - 14.
The program loops ten times to check if `numb1` matches `numb2`, and if it does, the program displays the number matched.

How can I get the total of `numb1`, for example if the out put was:

Output:

> i value:      2
>       numb1 value:  1
>
> i value:      3
>       numb1 value:  2
>
> i value:      10
>       numb1 value:  5
>
> "The total of numb1 is: 8" <-- how can i get the total?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            int numb1 = anyNumber();
            int numb2 = anyNumber();

            if (numb1 == numb2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i value:      " + i);
                Console.WriteLine("numb1 value:  " + numb1);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
    }


    static Random randNumb = new Random();
    static int anyNumber()
    {
        return randNumb.Next(1, 15);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to add a variable which will summ `numb1` values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

     int sum=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        int numb1 = anyNumber();
        int numb2 = anyNumber();


        if (numb1 == numb2)
        {
            sum+=numb1;
            Console.WriteLine("i value:      " + i);
            Console.WriteLine("numb1 value:  " + numb1);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
         Console.WriteLine("total is "+sum);
    }
}
```